# how to manipulate a custom attribute 'custom:variable_name' in Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, attributes, amazon-cognito

So, using AWS Cognito I created a custom attribute (special_name) which I can access using axios and AWS's Auth.currentUserInfo(). Using my browser's JavaScript console I can see the variable as:

attributes: custom:special_name: 'foo'

Great.

But if I console.log(custom:special_name) I get errors or at best 'undefined'

I'm using Visual Studio Code which really doesn't like the format custom:special_name.

I've already searched on this site and the ideas given, e.g. ['custom: special_name'] also don't work.

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious.

Please put me out of my misery.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if colons are allowed, but try `element.getAttribute('custom:special_name');`

Comment: Thank you but I didn't try it as an another answer hit the mark. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But if I console.log(custom:special_name) I get errors or at best 'undefined'

Did you mean:

```js
attributes['custom:special_name']
```

It seems your variable is a member of the `attributes` object, not a global one. In that case, the square bracket syntax will work.

Comment: Thank you - that works - and you put me out of my misery